# Loop instances appends string infinitely

Tags: python, oop

I have attempted to code in OOP a table that will return some statistical metrics for algorithms, and display in a pandas DataFrame in Python.

I am having the issue where for each instance the name of the column appends an additional string "predicted" to the DataFrame being created (example at the end).

my code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, accuracy_score, cohen_kappa_score, recall_score, accuracy_score, precision_score, f1_score
from sklearn import metrics

#----------------------------------------------------------------#        
####################### ROC metrics table ########################
#----------------------------------------------------------------# 


class roc_table:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data


    def viewer():


        #count columns in dataframe
        count_algo = len(data.columns)

        for i in data.iloc[:,1:]:
            data['predicted_{}'.format(i)] = (data[i] >= threshold).astype('int')

        rock_table = {
            "AUC":[round(roc_auc_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2) for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]],
            "Accuracy":[round(accuracy_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2) for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]],
            "Kappa":[round(cohen_kappa_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2)for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]],
            "Sensitivity (Recall)": [round(recall_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2) for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]],
            "Specificity": [round(accuracy_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2) for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]],
            "Precision": [round(precision_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2) for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]],
            "F1": [round(f1_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2) for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]]
        }   

        rock_table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rock_table, orient = 'index').reset_index()
        col = ['metrics']
        col.extend([x for x in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]])
        rock_table.columns = col    

        return rock_table
```

this line is giving me trouble:

```
for i in data.iloc[:,1:]:
            data['predicted_{}'.format(i)] = (data[i] >= threshold).astype('int')
```

an example of the outputs I get when run it:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your OOP implementation.
You are mutating the orginal data passed to the "**roc_table**" class.

Please try the following:

```
class roc_table:
def __init__(self, data):
    self.org_data = data


def viewer(self, threshold):

    #make a copy of initial data
    data = self.org_data.copy()

    #count columns in dataframe
    count_algo = len(data.columns)

    for i in data.iloc[:,1:]:
        data['predicted_{}'.format(i)] = (data[i] >= threshold).astype('int')

    rock_table = {
        "AUC":[round(roc_auc_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2) for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]],
        "Accuracy":[round(accuracy_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2) for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]],
        "Kappa":[round(cohen_kappa_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2)for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]],
        "Sensitivity (Recall)": [round(recall_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2) for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]],
        "Specificity": [round(accuracy_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2) for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]],
        "Precision": [round(precision_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2) for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]],
        "F1": [round(f1_score(data.actual_label, data[i]),2) for i in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]]
    }   

    rock_table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rock_table, orient = 'index').reset_index()
    col = ['metrics']
    col.extend([x for x in data.iloc[:,count_algo:]])
    rock_table.columns = col    

    return rock_table
```

and then instantiate the class like this and use:

```
rt = roc_table(data)
threshold=0.5
rt.viewer(threshold)
threshold=0.75
rt.viewer(threshold)
```

This way the original data is not mutated.

Hope this helps.